# Взаимодействие Spinner и EditText

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!

Работаю с этой [библиотекой](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject). В `Spinner` есть список стран с телефонными кодами. Мне нужно получить код страны в `EditText` с номером телефона при выборе страны.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_book);

    ccp = (CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.country_cod_picker);
    phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number_edit_text);

    ccp.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCountrySelected() {
    countryCode = ccp.getSelectedCountryCode();
    phoneNumberEditText.setText(countryCode);
    }
  });
}
```

Код xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PhoneBookActivity">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

     <TextView
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/country"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/phone_book_text_size"/>

    <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
        app:textSize="@dimen/phone_book_widgets_text_size"
        app:showFullName="true"
        app:defaultNameCode="UA"
        app:contentColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:id="@+id/country_cod_picker"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/phone_number"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/phone_book_text_size"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:id="@+id/phone_number_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textSize="@dimen/phone_book_text_size"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что проблема в том, что Ваш код скопирован из `onCreate`, и Вы пытаетесь получить `countryCode` ещё при инициализации, до того, как он был действительно выбран. Если это действительно так, переместите вызов `ccp.getSelectedCountryCode()` внутрь обработчика события `onCountrySelected()` и всё должно заработать.

```
ccp.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCountrySelected() {
            phoneNumberEditText.setText(ccp.getSelectedCountryCode());
        }
    });
```

---

UPD: Посмотрел исходники: Вы неправильно пользуетесь фрагментами, советую больше почитать на эту тему, например, [в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru).

Приведённый выше XML-файл относится вовсе не к `PhoneBookActivity`, а к `AddFragment` и инициализироваться должен там же. Переместите всё, что имеет отноешение к выбору телефонного кода из активити во фрагмент. Должно получиться так:

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment{

    private CountryCodePicker ccp;
    private String countryCode;
    private EditText phoneNumberEditText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
        ccp = (CountryCodePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.country_code_picker);
        phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_number_edit_text);
        ccp.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCountrySelected() {
                countryCode = ccp.getSelectedCountryCode();
                phoneNumberEditText.setText(countryCode);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Соответственно в `PhoneBookActivity` необходимо убрать всё, что относится к `ccp`, `phoneNumberEditText` и `countryCode`. Проверял на Android 6.0.1 -- работает.

Comment: Уже сделал так - теперь приложение крашится. Я уже неделю сижу и не могу понять в чем дело. NullPointerException дает. Может подскажите еще что-то?

Comment: @bogach4312 Значит какая-то из переменных у Вас равна `null`. Добавьте Ваш файл разметки (XML) и полный код инициализации вьюх (просто скопируйте содержимое `onCreate` Вашей активити)

Comment: Вверху все отредактировал. Такой вариант как сейчас, посмотрите.

Comment: @bogach4312 С виду всё хорошо. Поля `ccp` и `phoneNumberEditText` точно нигде не обнуляются?

Comment: Я их здесь только и использую. Хм..но я объявляю их вне пределов onCreate(). CountryCodePicker ccp; EditText phoneNumberEditText; - вот так. Я сам уже неделю, каждый вечер сижу всматриваюсь и не понимаю что не так.

Comment: @bogach4312 Создал чистый проект, скопировав туда Ваш код. Удалил только `android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle"` потому как не знаю, что там за стиль, да и не важно. Всё работает, но есть один нюанс: библиотека работает только, если используете `appcompat-v7` и наследуетесь от `AppCompatActivity`, а не от обычной `Activity`.

Comment: И у вас в EditText отображается код страны? Ладно, я если что скину проект полностью на гитхаб и там посмотрите, хорошо?

Comment: Да, и в EditText отображается код. Добавляйте ссылку на гитхаб.

Comment: https://github.com/aleks3433/PhoneAssistant
Вот ссылка, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @bogach4312 Честно говоря, не знаю, получите ли Вы нотификацию от изменении ответа, потому напишу заодно сюда. Обновил ответ с учётом Вашего кода.

Comment: ага..ну я подозревал что это нужно во фрагменте писать..ну это мое первое приложение, поэтому путаюсь. Спасибо. А инфлейтер этот, это что?

Comment: Это штука, которая преобразует XML-разметку в дерево из View-объектов. Подробнее [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) или [тут по-русски](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/80-urok-40-layoutinflater-uchimsja-ispolzovat.html). Не забудьте отметить ответ на основной вопрос как правильный, если он решил Вашу проблему.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вроде все логично, не знаю чего я его в активити пихал. А можете дать свой контакт какой-либо, я на прямую буду спрашивать если что.